# Laravel, Singleton - how to send data to all controllers?

Tags: laravel, session, singleton

I'm doing shopping site. I made Cart Model, which is Singleton. My shopping cart exists in session always ( no matter or User is login or not ). Now I have to invoke every time in every Controllers and actions getInstance to check or there's key "cart".
Is there a possibility to do this automaticly for all views?

Here is code of my Singleton:

```
class Cart
{
private $cartModel;
private static $instance;

private function __construct()
{
    $this->cartModel = new CartModel();
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    if ($cart == null) {
        Session::put('cart', array());
    }

}

private function __clone()
{
}

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (self::$instance === null) {
        self::$instance = new Cart();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function get(){

    return Session::get('cart');
}

}
```

And here for example how it looks in Controllers and actions:

```
class StoreController extends Controller
{

public function mainSite()
{
    $cart=Cart::getInstance()->get(); 
    return View('zoo');

}

public function showCategory($categoryName)
{
    $cart=Cart::getInstance()->get();
    $category = new Category();
    $categoryId = (int)$category->getCategoryId($categoryName);

    $subCategories = Subcategory::where('category_id', $categoryId)->get();

    return View('zoo-category', ['subCategories' => $subCategories, 'categoryName' => $categoryName]);

}

public function showSubcategory()
{

$cart=Cart::getInstance()->get();
}
```

I have to do this all the time: $cart=Cart::getInstance()->get();
Is there a possibility to do this only one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of Laravel's dependency injection.  Bind your class to the IoC container and you can either access it through the IoC container or you can have Laravel automatically inject this into your controllers in several different ways.

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container

Comment: Thanks for advice. I wrote whole subcject and It works too.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to base controller's constructor so that it gets called on every controller method.

```
// app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

protected $cart;

public function __construct()
{
    $this-> cart = Cart::getInstance()->get();
}
```

But i honestly see no point in your singleton class. All it does is set the cart with an empty array when it's not defined. Also `$this->cartModel = new CartModel();` is this ever used?

Comment: I want to exist cart always. As a user you can add products to your cart without login, but when you want to order sth and pay, the You have to be register and login. After login your cart witch you created before will be added to your account (session user ). And  You're right. cartModel will be never used :P. My mistake. Thank's for the answer!